# What is the most efficent way to get a Range "set difference" in Excel Automation?

Tags: excel, automation

Given a pair of ranges, where one is known to contain elements of another:

```
src = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
sel = src.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
```

what is the most efficient way to get a new range that represents the set difference
between these two ranges, i.e., the cells in `src` that are *not* in `sel`?

This can be done using a loop over the cells in `src`, but this requires `m * n` Automation calls for an `m` by `n` range, which does not have very good performance, and I'm hoping for something that involves fewer remote API calls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is any better way than looping through each cell in src.  The Excel.Application object has the Intersect function, which tells you what cells are contained in two or more ranges, but not the opposite.  You can also perform a union which just gives you a range with all the cells in two or more ranges...

But I think you're going to have to go through each cell in src and see if it's in sel...

```
Function GetInvisibleCells() As Range
    Dim src As Range, sel As Range

    Set src = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
    Set sel = src.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Dim Isection As Range
    Set Isection = Application.Intersect(src, sel)

    Dim Result As Range

    Dim cl As Range
    For Each cl In src ' Go find all the cells in range2 that aren't in Isection
        If Application.Intersect(cl, Isection) Is Nothing Then
            ' Cl is not in sel
            If Not Result Is Nothing Then
                Set Result = Range(Result, cl)
            Else
                Set Result = cl
            End If
            ' Debug.Print Cl.Address & " is in " & src.Address & " and not in " & sel.Address
        End If
    Next cl
    Application.Intersect
    Set GetInvisibleCells = Result

End Function
```

There are a few approaches detailed [here](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2007/08/17/two-new-range-functions-union-and-subtract/)

Answer (score 5):

Have you tried using Excel's built-in formulas to filter the data?  For example, the following formula will print "Yes" if the value in cell A2 is found in column D.  In your case, you could simply grab all the cells which do not have the corresponding "Yes".

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,D:D, 0)>0,"Yes","No")
```

Answer (score 4):

To extend Tom E's answer, the one issue I am having is that when there is NOT a match, `=MATCH()` returns `#N/A`, which the whole function doesn't like.

To fix this issue you can make the following alteration to the equation:

```
=IF(ISNA(MATCH(A2,D:D, 0)),"No","Yes")
```

The `ISNA()` effectively converts a number to `Yes` and a `#N/A` (for no match) to `No`, which is what we want. Note that I had to flip the order of the Yes and No due to how `ISNA()` functions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of going about it.
According to the `ColumnDifferences` method [reference from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa223836%28v=office.11%29.aspx):
"*Returns a `Range` object that represents all the cells whose contents are different from the comparison cell in each column*".

Based on this I applied the following strategy:

(1) Store the contents of `src` to a `Variant`.

(2) Substitute the contents of `sel` with something completely random.

(3) Use the `ColumnDifferences` method to get the desired range.

(4) Return the original values of `src`, which are stored in the `Variant`.

An implementation of the above steps follows:

```
Dim src As Range, sel As Range, rngDiff As Range, varTempStorage As Variant
Dim icnt1 As Long, icnt2 As Long

Set src = ActiveSheet.UsedRange
Set sel = src.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

' Store the src values in a variant
varTempStorage = src.Value

' Fill up the visible range with something random
sel.Value = "something completely random"

' Will return an error if nothing is found so needs appropriate error handling
' If it works, it should set rngDiff to point to the hidden cells only
Set rngDiff = src.ColumnDifferences(Comparison:=src(1,1))

' Pass data from variant to range - method taken from CPearson's website
Set src = src(1, 1)
src.Resize(UBound(varTempStorage, 1), UBound(varTempStorage, 2)).Value = varTempStorage

' Have a look at the output
For icnt1 = 1 To rngDiff.Rows.Count
    For icnt2 = 1 To rngDiff.Columns.Count
        Debug.Print " address: "; rngDiff(icnt1, icnt2).Address; " value: "; rngDiff(icnt1, icnt2)
    Next icnt2
Next icnt1
```

The `RowDifferences` method should give the same results - this is because we substitute all cells in the visible range so both methods behave the same way.

I checked the above by generating random numbers in rows 1 - 17 and columns A - U, and by hiding rows 7 - 10 and it did the job.